# Vidyo.io participant invitations

Tags: vidyo

My requirement is to invite participants to attend the vidyo.io resource meetings in android app.
I am not sure how to send the invitation with resource /  meeting details to the participants to connect or to a specific participant.

Firebase uses push notifications to send the invite, do you suggest to use the same in android app.

Please share your inputs.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would use push notifications from firebase to invite participants. All you need to send is the resourceId (room name) the participant has to join. All the participants calling the VidyoClient connect method with the same resourceId will join the same room.

Note that for this to work, you have to create unique tokens for each participant.